# Object Detection - How to evaluate saved model weights?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch, object-detection

I've recently completed training an object detection model but only printed out the losses for each epoch. Since I have the saved model weights, how would I go about evaluating the accuracy/precision?

Here's how I've gone about training:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from detecto import core

training = core.Dataset(train/"")

validation = core.Dataset(val/"")

model = core.Model(["Frame"], device=device)

losses = model.fit(training, validation, epochs=10, learning_rate=0.005)

model.save('model_weights.pth')

print(losses)

plt.plot(losses)
plt.xlabel('Learning step')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to do something with the sklearn classification report? I only have one class though

Comment: Are you sure you instantiate a model using pure torch? It looks like you are using a custom model class potentially built with torch.

Comment: Sorry should of specified. Yes you're correct

Comment: If you share your full code and/or code for the model we may be able to help more.